# What is an alias in font-awesome?

Tags: font-awesome

On the Font Awesome [icons page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), some icons are listed with (alias) after them. What does that mean?

Comment: @downvoter How can I improve my question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The (Alias) means that there is more than one name for the font icon.  For Example, icon-dollar is also icon-usd.

EDIT: It is probably best to use the default name rather than the alias name if you don't know which to use.  Further, as the comment below states, use the name that best fits you activity or function.

Comment: I disagree, just use the name or alias matching your requirements best. "mail-forward" vs "share" f.e. If you're using this icon in a web mail client, you should use "mail-forward", because there might be an update for that icon in the future symbolizing the mail forwarding idea better than "share".